# How to optimize dirty cell optimization when using volatile formula in Excel (like INDIRECT() )?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is maybe a little advanced topic.

When you press F9 or recalculate the sheets, Excel tries first to find out what cells just might had a chance to be changed, so it can skip evaluating them at all. The algorithm searches all ancestors and ancestors' ancestors to find out if value of any of them has changed. If so, it proceeds to actual evaluation.

That would be, at least, as long as there's no "INDIRECT()" formula in the path. If there is, the algorithm assumes that the value of this formula is volatile (i.e. it always changes) and so evaluates all the descendants.

There are more volatile formulas: RAND, AREAS, CELL, COLUMNS, INDEX, INDIRECT, NOW, OFFSET, ROWS, TODAY. Some of them obviously should be volatile (like `RAND()`).

The question: is there any way of telling Excel, that a given cell that is treated volatile by Excel should in fact be kept as frozen, unless its ancestors change?

---

One way of resolving the problem is to write my own versions of Excel volatile functions in VBA. VBA functions are assumed not volatile.

The problem is that there is a relative high cost of VBA invocation. Another is the need of 'reinventing the wheel'. I hope there is a cheaper solution.

Comment: no-precisely because its ancestors are not direct references and excel does not keep track of them

Comment: When I run into big Excel formula evaluation performance issues, I ususally move the most cost intensive formulas into an equivalent VBA script which re-generates the relevant parts of the worksheets. I then usually make the user click some sort of "update sheet" button. The script then writes the calculated values directly into the sheet. Just having to perform the re-calculation once can cause a great performance improvement.

Comment: @JosieP but Excel should know, that when the reference is e.g. invalid, the formula is not-volatile. And even if not, as long as both the argument and the cells it directs to did not change (as in  `<B1>=INDIRECT("A1")` and <A1> is a constant) there is no way the result could have changed, so the formula doesn't need to be volatile again.

Comment: I wonder, how does OO's Calc handle this problem. AFAIK it shares the volatile-formula concept. But does it optimize matter further than Excel does?

Comment: that's my point-excel doesn't keep track of the cells pointed to by INDIRECT-it simply marks the formula as volatile and you can't change that (apart from avoiding volatile functions)

Comment: @JosieP Thank you. It's a pity, especially when Excel already keeps track of the indirect-referenced cells, when it tries to figure out  if there are circular references in the formulas.

Comment: it only checks that when it calculates-it's not the same as a direct reference

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you want, but...
Don't use Formulas.

A user defined formula won't help either because of the limitations of what you can do inside them.

Recommend as previous comment suggested moving calculation into a pattern similiar to...
 1. pull all sheet data into a 2D array.
 2. perform X transformations on data.
 3. push data back into an equaly sized sheet address, to the 2D array.